# cannot find symbol in net beans

Tags: java, javax.comm

i am having code which is using javax.comm lib file,i am getting error saying cannot find symbol.i want to know where exactly my jar file should be?i using windows xp and net beans ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Java Communications API](http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/) web page, there is no implementation for Windows XP:

> [...]
>
> Implementations of the API are currently available for Solaris SPARC, Solaris x86, and Linux x86.
>
> [...]

Comment: There isn't *currently* an implementation of the javax.comm API for windows available from there... but there used to be...  

http://www.coderanch.com/t/277786/Streams/java/What-happened-Windows-Comm-API

Sun EOLed it and surreptitiously removed all previous versions available.  

The OP may have an old version, or a third-party implementation of the spec.

Answer (score 2):

[Import jar into netbeans](http://gpraveenkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/abc-to-import-a-jar-file-in-netbeans-6-5/)

Do get it to run maybe also check

[The Java Communications API: A Working Example](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31915)